# Automator-generated apps - Backwards compatibility

Tags: automator, compatibility

In my experience apps created with automator on Mountain Lion don't work on a Snow Leopard machine. The opposite isn't true though: apps created with automator on Snow Leopard do work on a Mountain Lion machine.

I'm creating a very simple wrapper around a command line executable and using cocoa seems overkill. I want the app to work on as many versions of OSX as possible though, so backwards compatibility is a concern.

Any thoughts on that matter? How can I ensure that my Mountain Lion Automator app is backwards-compatible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how backward-compatible they are, but you can also save scripts as applications from AppleScript Editor.

Another option might be to use [Platypus](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus).

> Platypus is a developer tool for the Mac OS X operating system. It creates native Mac OS X applications from interpreted scripts such as shell scripts or Perl, Ruby and Python programs. This is done by wrapping the script in an application bundle along with a native executable binary that runs the script.